# Cannot compile inner class source files, resulting in error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, nested-class, inner-classes

The seem not to be able to compile the following main method:

```
public class MainMethod {

    public static void main(String []args){

        InnerizationClass outer = new InnerizationClass(); 
        InnerizationClass.StaticInnerClass inner = outer.StaticInnerClass(); //#1
        System.out.println(inner.getOuterClassVar());
        System.out.println(new InnerizationClass().locInnrMeth());
    }
}
```

And this is the InnerizationClass class:

```
public class InnerizationClass {

    String outerClassVar = "Outer Catism";
    static String outerClassVarStat = "Outer Static Catism";

    public static class StaticInnerClass{

        String innerClassVar = "Catism";

        public String getInnerClassVar(){

            return this.innerClassVar;
        }

        public String getOuterClassVar(){

            return InnerizationClass.outerClassVarStat;
        }
    }

    public String locInnrMeth(){

        class MethodLocalInnerClass{

            String methodLocalInrCls = "Method Local Catism";

            void printInner(){

                System.out.println(InnerizationClass.this.outerClassVar);
            }

        }

        return new MethodLocalInnerClass().methodLocalInrCls;   

    }

    public String getStaticOuterVar(){return null;}
}
```

I am getting the following error from #1 from the main method:

```
MainMethod.java:6 qualified new of static class
InnerizationClass.StaticInnerClass inner = outer.new StaticInnerClass();
1 error;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
public class MainMethod {

public static void main(String []args){

    InnerizationClass.StaticInnerClass inner = new InnerizationClass.StaticInnerClass(); //#1
    System.out.println(inner.getOuterClassVar());
    System.out.println(new InnerizationClass().locInnrMeth());
 }
}
```

since your inner class is static you don't need to create an instance of InnerizationClass